# app showing a black blank screen on clicking on "sign in with google" button in the sign in activity

Tags: java, android

> I'm trying to implement sign-up with google and have configured all
>   the settings listed in the guide by google. but on clicking on the
>   "sign up with google button" which i've created its showing a blank
>   screen and nothing is happening. please help me i'm new to android.
>   thanks in advance!
>
> this is my java file for sign-in

---

## SignInActivity.java

```
    package com.example.mansi.busezon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

/**
 * Activity to demonstrate basic retrieval of the Google user's ID, email address, and basic
 * profile.
 */
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // [START configure_signin]
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END configure_signin]

        // [START build_client]
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        // [END build_client]

        // [START customize_button]
        // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
        SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_LIGHT);
        // [END customize_button]
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // [START on_start_sign_in]
        // Check for existing Google Sign In account, if the user is already signed in
        // the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        updateUI(account);
        // [END on_start_sign_in]
    }

    // [START onActivityResult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
    // [END onActivityResult]

    // [START handleSignInResult]
    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            updateUI(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            updateUI(null);
        }
    }
    // [END handleSignInResult]

    // [START signIn]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signIn]

    // [START signOut]
    private void signOut() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        updateUI(null);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END signOut]

    // [START revokeAccess]
    private void revokeAccess() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        updateUI(null);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END revokeAccess]

    private void updateUI(@Nullable GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        if (account != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, account.getDisplayName()));

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                signOut();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }
 }
```

---

this is my XML file for sign-in

---

## activity_signin.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_grey_700"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.example.mansi.busezon.SignInActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/activity_chooser" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/google_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/g_top_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_google_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/googleg_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/title_text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/signed_out"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_optional_action"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:text="Optional Action"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue_grey_900">

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_out_and_disconnect"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/sign_out"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/disconnect_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/disconnect"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
              android:parentActivityName=".SELL_BUY"
              android:label="BuSezon">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".shoppingCart"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="Shopping Cart">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ProductDesc"
        android:label=""
        android:parentActivityName=".SellHomepage">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SigningUpActivity"
        android:label="sign up">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WishlistActivity"
        android:label="WishList"
        android:parentActivityName=".profile_page">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ClothingPage"
        android:label="Clothing" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SellHomepage"
        android:label="Seller Home"
        android:parentActivityName=".SELL_BUY">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProductDescription"
        android:label="Product Description"
        android:parentActivityName=".SellHomepage">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SELL_BUY"
        android:label="Sell/buy">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SELL"
        android:label="Sell">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BUY"
        android:label="Sell"
        android:parentActivityName=".SELL_BUY">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".profile_page"
        android:label="Profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".SELL_BUY">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Add_product"

        android:label="Add new product"
        android:parentActivityName=".SellHomepage">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".select_photos"
        android:label="Select Product Images"
        android:parentActivityName=".Add_product"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooserActivity"
        android:label="chooser">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignInActivity"
        android:label="sign in">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignInActivityWithDrive"
        android:label="@string/name_sign_in_activity"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyNoTitleActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".IdTokenActivity"
        android:label="@string/name_id_token_activity"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyNoTitleActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ServerAuthCodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/name_auth_code_activity"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyNoTitleActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RestApiActivity"
        android:label="@string/name_rest_activity"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyNoTitleActivity">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: can you include the layout file `activity_chooser.xml` please.. also the value of `@color/blue_grey_700`

Comment: Did you configure the Google API console for your project?? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating